# How to subtract today's date with a file's modification date in unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

For example:
echo $(date) - $(date -r sample.txt)

Output:
90 days(for example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC as in

```
echo $(expr $(date +%s) - $(date -r sample.txt +%s)) #!/bin/sh
echo $(($(date +%s) - $(date -r sample.txt +%s))) #/bin/bash
```

Comment: Hi @flederwiesel This is showing seconds. Thank you. I will convert this into days. Thanks for your time

Comment: Divide by number of seconds in a day.

Comment: Quite simple with [Double Parentheses](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-arithmetic.php#double): `echo $(( ( $(date +%s) - $(date -r sample.txt +%s)  ) / 86400))`

Answer (score 0):

One more way

```
$ ls -l peter.txt
-rwxrw-r--+ 1 pppp qqqq 149 Dec 15 18:39 peter.txt

$ echo  "(" $(date +%s) - $(date -r peter.txt +%s) ")/" 86400 | perl -nle ' print eval, " days" '
29.254537037037 days

$
```